# Application Loader - Create new Package from File (different languages)

Tags: ios, application-loader

Application loader supports the creation of inApp-Purchase items via an import template. I'd like to create a bunch of products with localized display name/description. The "Using Application Loader" doc says

> Displayed Name @@language@@
>   A user-visible display name (from 2 to 75 characters) where @@language@@ is a supported localized language. You can add a new column for each localized language display name.

I tried to use fr, de, zh-Hans for language adding additional columns but Application loader always displays the display name as for english. Has anyone got it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Simply the full Language without @@ or () i.e "Display Name Language"
e.g "Display Name French" And "Description French"

Comment: Not so easy... but how do I differentiate stuff like Portuguese Brazil and Portuguese Portugal or French France, French Canada, etc? Just putting French France or Portuguese Brazil is not working... Some times I think Apple hate developers. :(

Answer (score 0):

The language which you add using the following methods can be visible to the user according to the iPad language set using [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2371). You cannot edit the .itmsp without using Application Loader. Refer [this](http://www.openfilehelp.com/article/How-to-open-.ITMSP-file.html)

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

[image: screen4]

[image: screen5]

[image: screen6]

[image: screen7]

Comment: The question was how to use "New from file". If you have tenth of products to create it would drive you crazy if you had to add them as you showed.